# how to dynamically set kafka offset value in mule so that we can start processing from that particular offset

Tags: apache-kafka, mule, mulesoft, connector

I want to dynamically set the KAFKA offset, so that my processing starts from that same offset when we want, using mulesoft...

Let's take an example:
There are total 150 messages in kafka, and I want to start processing from the offset value 51 upto the last.. In the configuration we can take from beginning/from latest..
How can I achieve this using mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid reading the messages, but you can use the attribute `attributes.offset` of the last read to find the offset and avoid processing those messages whose offset number you are not interested in.